# Laravel Foreach: Undefined Variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Im trying to pull all customer information, it should work as its is a simple foreach looping over information. Totally confused as to why I'm getting an undefined variable, in theory should this not work?

**Route File:**

```
 Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
      // Get Customer (GET)
      Route::get('/customer/clientlist', array(
        'as' => 'clientlist',
        'uses' => 'CustomerController@getCustomers'
        ));
    });
```

**Model:**

```
class Customer extends Eloquent {
     //Mass assignment for security
     protected $fillable = array('address', 'city', 'postcode',
                          'phone', 'mobile', 'contact', 'user_id');    
    //protected $table = 'customers';
    public function user() {
       return $this->hasMany('User');
    }
  }
```

**Controller:**

```
class CustomerController extends BaseController {
    public function getCustomers() {
      $customers = Customer::all();
      //var_dump($customers);
      return View::make('customer.clientlist', array('customers'=>$customers));
    } 
  }
```

**View home:**

```
@extends('layout.main')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
  @if(Auth::check())
  <div class="row push">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <h2 class="intro">Welcome, {{ Auth::user()->username }}</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <button type="button" class="c-add btn btn-danger pull-right">
        Add Client
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>{{-- Close Row --}}
  <div class="client-form">
    @include('customer.client-add-form')
  </div>{{-- Close client form --}}
  <section id="cs-grid">
    <div class="customer-card col-md-4">
      <h2>Direct Furniture</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>Address: <b>595 Boom Road</b></li>
        <li>City: <b>Manchester</b></li>
        <li>Postcode: <b>BT11 9AB</b></li>
        <li>Tel: <b>028 9011 1162</b></li>
        <li>Mobile: <b>078 902 815 611</b></li>
        <li>Contact: <b>Brian McNally</b></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="customer-card col-md-4">
      <h2>Direct Furniture</h2>
      <address>
        795 Folsom Ave, Suite 600<br>
        San Francisco, CA 94107<br>
        <abbr title="Phone">Phone:</abbr> (123) 456-7890<br>
        <abbr title="Phone">Mobile:</abbr> (123) 456-7890
      </address>
      <address>
        <strong>Contact</strong><br>
        <a href="tel:555-555-5555">Andrew Ellis</a>
      </address>
    </div>
    @include('customer.clientlist')
  </section>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  @endif
</div>{{-- Close Container --}}
@stop
```

**View clientlist:**

```
@foreach($customers as $customer)
  <div class="customer-card col-md-4">
    <h2>{{ $customer->name }}</h2>
    <address>
       795 Folsom Ave, Suite 600<br>
       San Francisco, CA 94107<br>
       <abbr title="Phone">Phone:</abbr> (123) 456-7890<br>
       <abbr title="Phone">Mobile:</abbr> (123) 456-7890
    </address>
    <address>
       <strong>Contact</strong><br>
       <a href="tel:555-555-5555">Andrew Ellis</a>
    </address>
   </div>    
@endforeach
```

This is the error exception Im currently getting, I cant understand as to why I keep getting this, if I comment out the controller and put static information into the view it does work.

ErrorException

> Undefined variable: customers (View:/Users/Sites/nit/app/app/views/customer/clientlist.blade.php)
>   `<?php echo $__env->make('customer.clientlist', array('customers'=>$customers), array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem - you are including the `customer.clientlist` file in itself.

In your controller you call

```
return View::make('customer.clientlist', array('customers'=>$customers));
```

then in your view you call it again

```
@include('customer.clientlist', array('customers'=>$customers))
```

creating an infinite loop. I'm guessing it should be

```
@include('customer.viewclientlist', array('customers'=>$customers))
```

And as mentioned by @Joseph Silber - you dont actually need to pass in the array on the include anymore - so make it this to clean up your code:

```
@include('customer.viewclientlist')
```

Comment: so update the view name to -> viewclientlist? Will this also not have to be updated in the controller too, so it does not throw an undefined view name?

Comment: You need to update the @include() filename to be whatever your file is "View client list" that you put in your question. If you are not sure - update your question with the exact file names of your views and I'll tell you what to write.

Comment: The Shift Exchange, I updated the route -as statement, controller, main view and changed the name of the file to viewclientlist. Updated above.

Comment: Crippy - let me put it to you another way - You are doing "Return view::make('File1'). Then inside "File1" you are doing @include(File1). It should be @include(File2). You need to fix up your code to not have an infinite loop.

Comment: The Shift Exchange - I am doing "Return view::make('File1')". Inside my "File1" it contains the @foreach. Im including the "File1" template inside my "home" view as "@include(File1)" to render the foreach as a set of results. Is this totally wrong, now a little confused, appreciate your time over this.

Comment: Please put the EXACT filenames in your question. i.e. where you have "View which pull clientlist:" heading - change the heading to the EXACT file name. Same as "View viewclientlist:" - change the headings to the exact file names

Comment: And is "clientlist.blade.php" exactly as you have posted? Is there any more code inside that view file?

Comment: And when you "var_dump($customers)" inside your controller - does that work?

Comment: No it doesn't, still returning the ErrorException

Comment: change "var_dump($customers)" to "dd($customers->toArray())" - what does that show you? Do you see an array of customers?

Comment: Nothing again The Shift Exchange, Im gonna go break it down again and try rebuild it, I have followed the documentation, just puzzling! Really appreciate your help with it.

Comment: Yeah - I was going to suggest that - strip everything away - start fresh - and slowly build it back up until the error re-appears. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again, really appreciate the time spent over it!